# Format lvm from ext4 to xfs

Tags: ext4, xfs

I have an lvm partition with ext4 which I want to transform to XFS.
I stumble upon `fstransform` which looks like the right tool, but to transform the partition it needs to be unmounted which is a problem. When I ran umount /path .. it says that the partition is busy. with `fuser -m /path` I got the following result `/dev/dm-2:           24931c`.

Can you point me to the right way of transforming the drive?
Thanks.

Comment: `ps -fe | grep 24931` to see the process using that fs, using info from your example.

Comment: @Aaron What's wrong with `ps 24931`?